# Is connection pooling a must-have in ODP.NET?

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I am writing a nightly job to move data from SQL Server to Oracle using ODP.NET.

We use around 100 connection objects(independent of data) and we don't expect more than 1500 rows to transfer in a single run(in total).
The ODP.NET notes and materials I read never talk about keeping connection pooling off.

In dev, I keep the connection pooling off and it just works fine.

Is it advisable in the given scenario to keep the connection pooling off,(given all the connections are disposed properly after use)since:

1. It is a nightly job and there wont be much load on the Oracle server.
2. Connection Pooling might return stale connections, for which validate settings/exception handing needs to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason for pooling is performance, so if your nightly job runs within it's window, there's nothing wrong with what you are doing, especially since it keeps your implementation simple by not having to worry about dead connections.

That said, I wouldn't make this standard practice.  I rarely write code to handle stale connections and even then it's a simple factory.  The question starts with why do you have stale connections at all?  Typically this relates to either a firewall or a DBA job terminating idle connections, both of which should be changed or relaxed for an application account.  Even in that case you can do the following:

- Specify Min Pool Size=0 in your connection string.  Doing so lets ODP.net clean up even the last connection your app has, allowing your app to completely disconnect when it's idle for a long enough period.
- Specify a higher Decr Pool Size in your connection string.  This will allow for more idle connections to be closed every 3 minutes by ODP.net.
- You could try setting Validate Connection = true - My guess would be there's less overhead validating the connection than there is with opening one.

More info can be found here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167/featConnecting.htm#i1006228

Comment: We had this issue when firewalls would close our idle connections. Pool Size=0 seemed to have worked for us.

Comment: @b_levitt quick question for clarification... If pooling is enabled (by default) and I set the Min Pool Size = 0 - Isn't it same thing as disabling pooling?

Comment: No.  Settings like DecrPoolSize will slowly prune back the pool when the app is less busy.  Ie say the pool gets up to 45 connections, but current site load is only causing 15 of them to be used.  DecrPoolSize will release x connections at a time from the pool.  However, Min Pool Size I think has a default of 3 - this is problematic when a firewall or oracle terminates idle connections after a set time period.  If there are 3 connections in the pool for a long period of time, they may get severed.  Min Pool Size=0 will allow the pool to go to zero connections during these slow times.

Comment: I'll add to this that the default Min Pool Size is 0 for sql server.  I have no idea why Oracle chose 3.