# .net web service Oracle database connection issue

Tags: .net, web-services, oracle11g, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I have a .net web service I have inherited (asmx).  Everything is fine, until the database goes down for maintenance.  Once this happens, the web service can't connect to the Oracle 11g database until the app pool is recycled.  The web service uses a datalayer that other applications also use.  I have been looking around with out any luck on what could be causing the issue.  Any advice or experience with anything similar would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I found this article which sounds remarkably familiar.. but no luck getting any of their suggestions to work.      

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613960/odp-net-connection-pooling-issues-fault-tollerance-after-database-goes-down#comment36493442_23614129

Comment: I created a simple app to test the managed vs un-managed odp.net driver.  The managed version does not seem to have the above issue.  Its simple to switch between the 2 in my app, but our main app will need lots of testing with the new version before we could roll it out with managed.